# Struct holding references and life time annotations. Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to create a struct that will hold a bunch of Path references for later lookup.

I first started with this:

```
struct AbsoluteSystemPaths{
    home_folder:Path,
    shortcuts_file:Path
}
```

The compiler complained about -> Path doesn't have a size known at compile-time.

It is sensible, a struct can only have as much as one non sized var member and I added 2 (home_folder and shortcuts_file). So, I decided to move them to references:

```
struct AbsoluteSystemPaths{
    home_folder:& Path,
    shortcuts_file: &Path
}
```

That made the sized error go away but brought another one related to lifetimes: "Missing lifetime specifier" for the two var members of type Path.

And again, it is pretty sensible, Rust needs to know how much time this 2 references will live to avoid dangling references or memory leaks.

So, I added the life time specifiers:

```
struct AbsoluteSystemPaths<'a> {
    home_folder:&'a Path,
    shortcuts_file: &'a Path
}
```

and then everything compiled without errors.

What I would like to know is:

1. Is my general reasoning correct?
2. The lifetime annotations I added could be read as: Both path references will last at least as 'a that is the lifetime of an instance contrusted from AbsoluteSystemPaths struct?

Comment: 1. sounds good to me. 2. I'd word it as "the path references must live at least as long as the struct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

One thing to note with `Path`, as it is an unsized type as you've mentioned, is that the standard library provides a struct called [PathBuf](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) that represents "An owned, mutable path (akin to String).". This is an alternative to using `&Path` if you'd like your struct to own the `Path` instead of hold references to them. This may be useful depending on the way you're using your struct.